# How do I sequentially add to a field inside each customer?

Tags: javascript

When I click the button, I should add it to the itemSold field. But the example should be like this:

1. I click any button. The first element in the 'itemSold' array of the 1st customer is null. That's why he added it here.
2. I click any button. The first element in the 'itemSold' array of the 2nd customer is null. That's why he added it here.
3. I click any button. The second element in the 'itemSold' array of the 1st customer is null. That's why he added it here.
4. I click any button. The second element in the 'itemSold' array of the 2nd customer is null. That's why he added it here.

```js
let customers = [{
    active: true,
    id: 1,
    product: {
      itemSold: [null, null],
    },
  },
  {
    active: true,
    id: 2,
    product: {
      itemSold: [null, null],
    },
  },
];


let products = [
{id:1,name : 'car'},
{id:2,name : 'home'},
{id:3,name : 'phone'},
{id:4,name : 'fly'},
]
let productsContainer = document.querySelector(".productsContainer");


let productHTML = ``;
products.map((product) => {
  return (productHTML += `<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-item" id=${product.id}>${product.name}</button>`);
});


productsContainer.innerHTML = productHTML;
```

```html
<div class="productsContainer" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to be +- universal without storing any state it could be something like this

```
function addItem(item) {
 const nullIndexes = customers.map(c => c.product.itemSold.indexOf(null));
 if(nullIndexes.every(i => i == -1)) return;
 const minIndex = Math.min(...nullIndexes.filter(i => i != -1))
 for(var customer of customers) {
     if(customer.product.itemSold[minIndex] === null) {
         customer.product.itemSold[minIndex] = item;
         break;
     }
 }    
}
```

Some explanation

1. We need to know if there is any nulls left in arrays, for that we need to get indexes of nulls for each of the arrays `customers.map(c => c.product.itemSold.indexOf(null));`
2. Now we need to check, if nulls not found (all of the indexes are -1) then we done `if(nullIndexes.every(i => i == -1)) return;`
3. Then we need to get the correct index of value we need to replace, for that we need to have the least index that we found above, but not counting -1 (because -1 means that that particular array is already full) `const minIndex = Math.min(...nullIndexes.filter(i => i != -1))`
4. Now, all we have to do is to go over the customers and find that particular one that has null in the index we determined above and replace it.

Don't get me wrong - this is most likely not the best optimal way, but it is a solution

Comment: So what should I do if I want to check the occupancy of only the 0th index of the itemSold field of all customers?

Comment: Use .every method on customers and inside check if itemSold[0] != null

Comment: Please edit and  show me at the end of this post.

Comment: I cannot do it right now, leaving it for you to figure out :)

Comment: Thank you. I understood what you said and solved the problem. :)